# Trap layout for double vanity with existing stack

Tags: drain-waste-vent

Installing a double vanity with 4" stack on one side.  Typical in-wall double rough-in means drilling two-inch holes in multiple studs across an old exterior wall already hacked up by generations of plumbers.

I would like instead to service from the one stack on the left, with a suitable arrangement of drain pipes inside the vanity.  There is room at the back to do whatever I want and need.

1. The first diagram below has a 45 inch straight run between basins, before the trap.  I know that's not ok, but I don't know why.  This might be worth a separate question but if there's an easy explanation of how/why this produces siphoning or other problems I'd like to hear it.
2. The second diagram below has 23 inch runs from each basin to a common trap, and a 3 foot run from the trap to a vented 2 inch riser.  Is this ok?
3. The third diagram adds a vent to the horizontal from the trap.  Is this useful and/or necessary?

Photo of the actual site at the bottom.

A) 45 inch horizontal before trap.

[image]

B) Two 23 inch horizontals before, and 3 foot after trap.

[image]

C) Additional venting to (B).

[image]

Site, showing 2" riser to 4" drain below and dry vent above.

[image]

Comment: Code (at least the code I have to use) Says the **drains have to be within 30 inches** to share a trap, so you need two traps, regardless. At least as far as I recall. What code applies to you? Me, I'd use 2" all the way to the trap adapters, not that code requires that for the distance you're going, but I'm prone to "better than code" and fewer problems down the line.

Comment: IPC 1002.1 (**each** fixture shall be **separately** trapped) exception 2 permits single trap for less than 30" horizontal and 6" vertical difference between the drains for "combination fixtures"

Comment: Ok so I'm not achieving anything by putting the trap in the middle, the requirement is distance between the fixtures so I need two traps.  That's useful.  I'll comment further to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under IPC code, you need a trap for each fixture as I read the code. Don't know what code applies, but IPC and UPC are more similar than different, and most parts of the USA use one of those at least as the starting point before they delete or add bits based on local politics.

Code does not require 2", but I would choose to run a 2" pipe sloped at 1/4" per foot with a Wye (or Wye and 45) to a trap adapter for the first sink and an elbow to a trap adapter for the second sink right along the back wall of your cabinet, with the traps going "back out of the way" as much as possible (rather than "to the left" as shown - the drain line going to the left, but way at the back of the cabinet, and the traps going back to the drain line.)

The 2" pipe has generous vent space (to the point that even my "do better than code" sense is not feeling the need for a dry vent here) for this short of a run into a sanitary tee at the 2" vertical drain/vent loop.

Comment: I'm in NJ.  My sketchy sketches are not meant to show front-to-back positioning and yes I can orient things mostly flat along the back.     So I think you're saying  I can put a trap under the right hand sink, use 2 inch pipe, and run it *separately* to the 2 inch vented vertical pipe without a vent?   It's about 5 and a half feet.    I'll do another sketch in my own answer to hopefully get your feedback on that.

Comment: One 2" pipe. Two 1.5" or 1.25" traps into that one pipe. No need for a separate drain pipe, just separate traps. A wye (horizontal branch) for the left sink trap entrance. Could probably be 1.5" pipe and meet code, but **I would not,** especially with 1.5" traps. 2" is nominally good to 8 feet from the stack, wet venting.

Answer (score 1):

My unartistic rendering of @ecnerwal's answer -- hoping I've understood it.

[image]

Comment: This would probably be better as an edit to Ecnerwal's answer.

Comment: If I got it right and he doesn't mind having my poor artwork to his name, yes.

Comment: Eh, throw a comment in there. He can yoink it if he doesn't like it. ;)